# Failover scenarious for the Service Bus with NServiceBus or MassTransit

Tags: nservicebus, failover, masstransit

I need to build Identity server like Microsoft's http://login.live.com.

To handle failover I will have multiple web servers nodes. The plan is that all database write operations are done by sending messages to the database server. Database will be mirrored or replicated. The idea is that database subscribes to the write operations but that other nodes subscribe also. That way other nodes do not need to read from database and can update their caches.

I am just starting to learn the service bus architecture and what is not clear to me is how to handle failover scenario for the service bus.

**Question:**

1. If database server is not available, what will happen with the published messages ?
2. Will they be stored somewhere and where ?
3. Do I need additional machine or a cluster to handle failover of the service bus?
4. I read that SQL Server can be used as a message store but can I use durable MSMQ? I am queuing messages to be able to write them to the database so why would I store them to the DB first just to take them and write them again? OR, I am getting this wrong and DB is only used for the list of subscriptions and not for the Messages?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. This will depend on how it is setup, but in MassTransit you can leave the subscription active so the message will still be delivered to the queue for the DB. When the DB is active again, you can read the messages in the queue.
2. Each service connected to a service bus, in MassTransit, has an active queue for itself. The messages will be stored there.
3. I think this is a "it depends"... MassTransit has support for other MQs than MSMQ but is really built around MSMQ. We have no experienced great support for things such as failover from MSMQ. However, everything will continue to run without fault if the subscription service (i.e. the bus) fails - the services already know who to talk to. It's only when a change in a consumer (subscribe or unsubscribe) where this becomes a problem. For me, that's an event that happens almost never.
4. With MassTransit, we use the DB to store the subscription states but all the messages are stored in MSMQ.

If you'd like more details in one of these responses or have additional questions about MT, you can join us on the mailing list: http://groups.google.com/group/masstransit-discuss.

Answer (score 9):

Whe implementing this kind of architecture, you should look at applying the principles of CQRS - queries (is this user/pwd combo valid) should not be done via the bus; commands (change pwd, forgot pwd) are sent via the bus, not published as events. While internally you will likely use events to keep the command and query sides in sync, this doesn't involve the client.

Queries can be done using simple ado.net against the replicated-read-slaves of your DB - what's known as the persistent view model in CQRS. If you like, you can put some simple WCF in front of that too.

When using MSMQ, all messages are delivered via store-and-forward. That means that they're first stored on the client before being delivered to the server, so if the server is down, the messages sit on the client waiting. For fault-tolerance, you will want your messages to be recoverable (written to disk) - this is the default in NServiceBus but not the default of standard MSMQ (don't know about MassTransit). You don't need the database for this.

In NServiceBus, the bus is not installed on a separate machine so you don't need to deal with its availability independently of the rest of the system. It's only when you look at scaling our your command processing to more nodes that you might consider using the message-based load balancer in NServiceBus (called the distributor) which, for high availability, should be installed on a cluster or fault-tolerant hardware.